# SSIS 2008 Connection Managers (Project Specific) and Corresponding Configurations

Tags: ssis, configuration

These are the requirements that I want to complete:

a. I want the package to only use connection managers that are project/not package bound.

b. I also want these connections to be bound to the ssis config so that I can migrate these packages and they will connect to the correct environment seamlessly

c. I want to make sure this will work for pre-validation runs of the package so that it will validate its meta data against the db in the config rather than the hardcoded values in the package

So, my questions/concerns are:

How could I make my connection managers Project and NOT package specific?

I want to take these project specific connection managers and relate them to SSIS configurations

Is there a way to have both SSIS configuration (Config Tables) and store those values in an Environment Variable?

Any help is well appreciated. I know project bound connection managers are available in SSIS 2012, but i'm looking for an equivalent method in SSIS 2008